# What is the best way to get ID of asp control in external javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, external

I'm trying to get asp control in external .js file. I know, that ID attribute generated by the server is unpredictable and ClientID I can use only on the same page inside . I found couple ways how to get element ID in External file, but they all weird...

Any help, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple options, you can either pass in the generated ID or you can control the ID that is generated.

**Option 1 - Pass in the ID to your javascript function**

```
foo( '<%# MyPanel.ClientID %>' );
```

**Option 2 - ClientIDMode** 
With .NET 4, you can use the ClientIDMode property to "Static" to have ASP.NET render the server side ID.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

ASP.NET

```
<asp:Panel id="MyPanel" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">...</asp:Panel>
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
$("#MyPanel").foo(..);
```

Comment: Is it any other ways to do this without this property?

Comment: You can pass in the generated ID value, see the updated answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The ClientIDMode property makes things a lot simpler for me!